# viPlugin key mapping, how to map <enter>

Tags: vi

I have some question about viPlugin, Could you give me some help?

1. how to pageup or pagedown, the   doesn't work.
2. In the Map Commands, how to map

   ```
   ,wa :wa<cr>  does't work as in VIM

   ,wa :wa<ENTER> the file saved, but also lost the focus
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the CTRL buttons to work you have to set the viPlugin keyscheme in the preferences and also double-check that the same keys are not mapped already by another plugin.
I just tried it and yes, the focus is lost. I will search for the bug ;)

The above reply is what I got from the viPlugin writer